# Why repassing dynamic parameter to params parameter fails to build

Tags: c#, dynamic, params-keyword

When repassing a dynamic parameter to a method with params keyword the solution fails to build, I am using .NET 4.6 and VS2015, but the problem also happens with previous versions of .NET Framework. No error is produced on Error List, just a "Build Failed" message at the bottom.

This is the sample code I am trying to run:

```
public void MethodWithDynamicParameter(dynamic dyn)
{
    MethodWithParams(dyn); //This fails to build!

    MethodWithParams(new object[] { dyn }); //This compiles!
}

public void MethodWithParams(params object[] objects)
{

}
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with the first call?

EDIT 1:

I´ve created a new solution with the sample provided by Dave and it builds with no problems. But in my solution the problems persists even after "Close, clean and build". It does not matter if I pass a string, a object, a dynamic or anythin else. At the image below there are no calls to method and the solution still does not build.

[image]

Comment: They both compile for me - are you expecting `dyn` to be a collection of parameters or a single parameter?

Comment: @DStanley In practice it would be a single value, but in the solution it fails to compile with any provided parameter: string, object, dynamic or array of objects

Comment: You're absolutely certain that is not compiling?  It's odd that you're not getting any message other than "Build Failed".  do you have any unit test or anything that are tied to your build process?

Comment: Your edit proves that the syntax is valid at compile-time, so there must be something else that is preventing the build.

Comment: There is no way SO can help you based on current state of the post. You'd have to investigate yourself. If you come up with [MCVE] - update post so someone can answer. If you find root cause - consider posting self-answer (if it does not turn out to be unrelated mistake).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new Console Application using the following code as a test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test with object:
        object x = new object();
        MethodWithDynamicParameter(x);

        // Test with specific type of object, a string:
        MethodWithDynamicParameter("string");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void MethodWithDynamicParameter(dynamic dyn)
    {
        MethodWithParams(dyn);
        MethodWithParams(new object[] { dyn });
    }

    static void MethodWithParams(params object[] objects)
    {

    }
}
```

For me, the program both compiles and runs without error.

May I suggest the standard "close all documents, clean all, rebuild all" and/or "restart Visual Studio" solutions, if you have not yet attempted this?

---

Additionally, they `dynamic` keyword might be the source of your troubles, as it bypasses many of the typing checks until compile time.  Try checking your code from where `dyn` would be declared, prior to making the call to `MethodWithDynamicParameter(dynamic dyn)`.

Comment: Also, some [dot net pearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic) on the `dynamic` keyword.